# Using MetaProgramming to Add collectWithIndex and injectWithIndex similar to eachWithIndex

Tags: groovy

Please help with a metaprogramming configuration such that I can add collections methods called collectWithIndex and injectWithIndex that work in a similar manner to eachWithIndex but of course include the base functionality of collect and inject.  The new methods would accept a two (three with maps) argument closure just like eachWithIndex.  I would like to have the capability to utilize these methods across many different scripts.

Use case:

```
List one = [1, 2, 3]
    List two = [10, 20, 30]
    assert [10, 40, 90] == one.collectWithIndex { value, index ->
    value * two [index]
    }
```

Once the method is developed then how would it be made available to scripts?  I suspect that a jar file would be created with special extension information and then added to the classpath.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a place, where you request someone to write your code.
You should __try to do it yourself__, and if you are facing specific issue during that - ask a __specific__ question, and include __your current progress__ in it. That way you'll show your report and progress made so far.
If it's a feature request - submit it in groovy [bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY/) or raise a topick in mailing list. See [contribute](http://groovy-lang.org/contribute.html).

Comment: I would have posted code if I could get my head around closures and functional programming.  I do not know how to write a method called collectWithIndex that is executed from a list or map object that takes a closure as an argument.

Comment: I have added an answer. Beware, others will minus you, and ignore this question. And, honestly speaking, they will be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still sure, it's not a proper SO question, but I'll give you an example, how you can enrich metaclass for your multiple scripts.

Idea is based on basescript, adding required method to List's metaClass in it's constructor. You have to implement collect logic yourself, through it's pretty easy. You can use wrapping

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

class WithIndexInjector extends Script {
    WithIndexInjector() {
        println("Adding collectWithIndex to List")
        List.metaClass.collectWithIndex {
            int i = 0
            def result = []
            for (o in delegate) // delegate is a ref holding initial list.
                result << it(o, i++) // it is closure given to method
            result
        }
    }

    @Override Object run() {
        return null
    }
}

def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.scriptBaseClass = WithIndexInjector.name
new GroovyShell(configuration).evaluate('''
    println(['a', 'b'].collectWithIndex { it, id -> "[$id]:$it" })
''')
// will print [[0]:a, [1]:b]
```

If you like to do it in more functional way, without repeating collect logic, you may use wrapping proxy closure. I expect it to be slower, but maybe it's not a deal. Just replace `collectWithIndex` with following implementation.

```
List.metaClass.collectWithIndex {
    def wrappingProxyClosure = { Closure collectClosure, int startIndex = 0 ->
        int i = startIndex
        return {
            collectClosure(it, i++) // here we keep hold on outer collectClosure and i, and use call former with one extra argument. "it" is list element, provided by default collect method.
        }
    }
    delegate.collect(wrappingProxyClosure(it))
}
```

*offtopic: In SO community your current question will only attract minuses, not answers.*

Comment: Or just do `['a', 'b', 'c'].indexed().collect { index, val -> [ val, index ] }`

Comment: Or `['a', 'b', 'c'].indexed().inject([]) { list, index, val -> list << [ val, index ] }`

Comment: @tim_yates Cool, it's smth new. I haven't noticed it's added =). AFAICS it's a transformation to map, and therefore have significant memory tradeoff, ~2*N for conversion, and access. But it's definitely nice.

Comment: Answer accepted but concerned that the question response does not demonstrate how this would apply to making new collectWithIndex and injectWithIndex methods available to multiple scripts unless each script has to include all of the code in the example with the original script wrapped in the evaluate method.  

Forgive me but I do not understand how this is off-topic.  It is a Groovy question with the Groovy tag.